# When icons are used as glyphs, is it necessary to create them at double the intended resolution?

Tags: vector, icon, interface-design, ppi, glyphs

eg. 16x16 is the intended size, do I need to create them at 32x32 or higher for sharpness on screens with high ppi? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: looks like I was conflating characteristics of a rasterized image with vector images. a rasterized image would have pixels embedded in the image while an SVG image is independent of pixel density thus creating them at the intended size will not result in blurriness on any device correct?

Comment: Any **image** which you wish to appear sharper on high resolution screens should be larger.

Comment: well, if it's vector and it has enough detail... maybe not

Comment: If you are using vector image editing software, then I'd say it's not necessary.  You could easily create the different size icons you need when you output the raster files.

Comment: oh... I missed the vector tag and was thrown off by all the ppi talk... which is irrelevant for vectors.

Comment: Unless your icons *already consist of squares and rectangles*, you will be hugely disappointed with their 16x16 version – and likely with the slightly larger versions as well. Such small icons are best created with actual pixel editing tools, one pixel at a time.